# using dynamic_reconfigure forces a rebuild of the package

Tags: rosmake, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 with fuerte.
I noticed, that if my packages use dynamic_reconfigure the config header is generated every time I call make. So the whole package is rebuild, even no file was changed.

Did anyone else observed this problem? Is there a solution?

Tanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50818/using-dynamic_reconfigure-forces-a-rebuild-of-the-package/) by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1480 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-19**:
I think that's a pretty old issue that noone fixed so far. I'm not sure if there's a ticket already though and I don't know who's maintaining dynamic_reconfigure at the moment. To fix it, you probably just need to fix the dynamic_reconfigure cmake target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a bug in the recent dynamic_reconfigure version and should be fixed with 1.5.29. Basically the command failed to generate the docs in the correct location and therefore always regenerated the headers/Python files.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2012-12-20**:
how can I update dynamic_reconfigure to 1.5.29? I'm using the ros ubuntu repository.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2012-12-21**:
That version is currently only available for Groovy but the fix might be backported to Fuerte soon.

**Comment by [klapow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2577/klapow/) on 2012-12-21**:
1.5.29 is in groovy but I am working on back-porting the fix. Should be available in a day or so.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-01-08**:
Are there any updates?